# Connect to database using hazelcast client-server topology

Tags: java, openshift, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In embedded topology of hazelcast we can connect to database if data is not present in IMap using Mapstore.
But I am using openshift to create multiple hazelcast nodes and trying to connect these members using a JAVA client.

My issue is where I need to write mapstore configurations for this topology

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, your mapstore code need to be deployed with Hazelcast members, it needs to be on each members classpath & config as well. If you cannot deploy it, you can use User Code Deployment feature to load those classes to Hazelcast cluster as well.